# Thin conceptions of time

Tags: reference-request, terminology, time

[WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thick_concept) says:

> In philosophy, a thick concept (sometimes: thick normative concept, or
>   thick evaluative concept) is a kind of concept that both has a
>   significant degree of descriptive content and is evaluatively
>   loaded... Thick concepts thus seem to occupy a 'middle position'
>   between (thin) descriptive concepts and (thin) evaluative concepts.

I know there are lots of different ways to think about time: e.g. McTaggert's A B and C series. I assume time has many other theories about it.

Has any philosopher or philosophy tried to *make time thin*? Detached the descriptive aspect of "times" from their normative component?

So e.g. using McTaggert's A series: an A property cannot tell us anything about value.

I would imagine the conventional pre philosophical idea of time is that timing can have a normative component (my wedding is in just three days, that's such a good thing): so if time is in this sense "thin" it would have some currency.

I personally have a number of reasons to wonder if time is thin, too various to explain here: the modern lyric; an interest in mythological characters who represent time; in the meaning of my own death; in boredom and flux; etc..

Comment: Your question assumes that the concept of time is thick. Could you expand on this or give some references? What are the normative aspects of time?

Comment: no it doesn't assume that, why do you suppose it does ???

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN Please define your meaning of *thin concept*. Your post sounds as if you consider a concept a *thin concept* if it's neither descriptive nor normative. But then, which property is left?

Comment: As I understand it, the question itself is quite clear and could be reformulated as follows: "As a thick concept is here defined as both descriptive and evaluative; are there philosophers who tried to establish a concept of time either only descriptive or only evaluative, thus a thin concept?"

Comment: @Philip Klöcking If I take your definition - which is clearly stated: I cannot imagine anyone who considers time other than a thin concept with solely a descriptive component. Do you imagine any normative component of the concept time?

Comment: hi, i did mean "thin" as in not **both** descriptive and evaluative. i see that the question has caused some confusion though: i'm not at all asking anything at all trivial - if anything i would guess it's *too* outlandish to consider (that timing as opposed to sequence doesn't ever matter)

Comment: I actually do not, but it seems to be an interesting thought. In gereneral, the question what time *should be* like is kinda weird...

Comment: There are several discussions on *time* in this blog. Insofar as one asks about the objective concept of time - not the subjective experience of time - the best answer I know, is from the Special Theory of Relativity: Time is one of the four *relative* coordinates of an event in *absolute* spacetime. One should not fall back behind the state of science expressed by Minkowski in his famous 1908 talk.

Comment: @mathematician you say "Detached the descriptive aspect of times from their normative component" so you assume that time has both components, that it is a "thick" concept. Why so? Which normative aspect do you see? If time is a "thin" descriptive concept your question doesn't make sense (nothing to detach), so please clarify the question.

Comment: @mathematician I've never heard of time as having normative aspects, as your question presupposes, so references are welcome.

Comment: @quen_tin i think most people in general would think that the timing of some events can have a normative component. i will edit the question to reflect my assumption

Comment: @mathematician after edition, from your examples, it seems that what you want to ask is: *has any philosophers tried to make time* ***thick*** (that is, normatively loaded).

Comment: no i don't think it is, because if they haven't we can still i think assume that time *is **thick***

Comment: @mathematician we can assume that, we don't have to and no philosopher I know did assume that. That's what you're asking: shall we assume that... No?

Comment: @mathematician in any case I think I understand your point now, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what troubles you is the difference between moments loaded with normative aspects and time itself. Our concept of a table is in itself purely descriptive, even if we can load a thought of a specific table normatively.

A normative aspect of time would be saying how time itself *should be* like. And I actually cannot imagine how to think this.

To clarify my point: Kant for example said that for conceiving objects we must conceive them in the form of time and space. Time therefore must, to him, be thought as part of the substance of what it means to be "something in the world" (Beware: this only holds for our very conceptions of these objects, not the objects themselves). But all concepts (in sense of "Begriffe") of what there is are descriptive, because they say what is needed to be "a table" or what we mean by "time". Normativity can only be attributed to concrete phenomena, let it be of an object, an event in time, or a concept (in sense of "Anschauung", perception of an object).

In the light of this, again: It is weird to say how "time" *should be* like, it is like it is. There can be wrong conceptions about what time is, but a philosophical concept will (or should) always be "thin" if it is not an ethical term (one could say that this is because ethics have no "real being" like objects and are purely phenomenal).

Comment: i'm not sure !! it's a little clunky

Comment: Upvoted +1; the answer clearly discriminates between a concept and the context of its use. Hence the answer covers much of the different comments to the question and to my own answer.

Comment: You don't answer the question. "Has any philosopher or philosophy tried to make time thin?"

Comment: @JoWehler asking "why downvoting" is not constructive. There are several questions about this on meta. I'm on my phone so adding a link is a little difficult, but it should be easy to find -- have a look.

Comment: On Meta I read divided opinions concerning downvoting without giving an explanation. Apparently, you and I differ concerning this practice.

Comment: @Keelan: I in fact (even before my last edit) explained why philosophers do not have to make it thin because it can hardly be concepted as "thick".

Comment: @JoWehler then learn from the fact that your comment was removed.

Comment: Philip: thanks for adding a reference; I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

After your edition, from your example, I understand your question as follows (correct me if I'm wrong):

*Has any philosopher attempted to distinguish a normative and a descriptive aspect in the concept of time (=interpreted time as a thick concept that would have both aspects, and then analysed the two components)?*

I don't know of any philosopher that interpreted time predicates ("now", "in three days", "yesterday"...) as intrinsically normative, or having a normative component. The closest I can think of is Bergson, who views time as irreducibly qualitative, and distinct from space, but that's still different from attributing normative aspects to time.

Your example emphasise the fact that we have intentional stances toward events which depend on their position in time relative to us: apprehension, nostalgy, ...
Note that space is not different in this regard: something being close or far away can imply different intentional stances (fear, desire, lack...).

However it seems to me that being thick or thin, descriptive or normative, is not a characteristic of occurrences but a generic feature of predicates and concepts. That means that a predicate is normative/descriptive/thick independently of its specific applications, but *in general*.

Take "good" for example. You can say that "*x* is good" evaluates *x* positively whatever x is. But "*x* is in three days" says nothing about how *x* should be evaluated: if it's a wedding that's good and if it's an exam and you're not prepared it might be less good.

Obviously our time relation to events will impact how we evaluate them but that doesn't mean that time predicates are themselves normative because it is not part of their meaning: the impact will depend on the circumstances (it can also be neutral such as: "a mosquito will die in three days" is neither good nor bad to me).

That's the difference, in philosophy of language, between semantic aspects (general meaning) and pragmatic aspects (use in context).

What philosophers are interested in when they employ the notion of thickness is the general meaning of terms out of context, i.e. the semantic aspects. I don't think that time predicates can be interpreted as thick out of context. However understanding how descriptive aspects are evaluated in context is still an interesting question.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i can't think of a counter example to your belief about universals

Answer (score 0):

None of the eminent thinkers like e.g., Aristotle, Newton, Leibniz, Kant, Einstein have attributed a normative aspect to time. I think neither do McTaggart' A,B,C series. Notwithstanding all made different and partially incompatible statements about the concept of time, they all considered time a *descriptive* concept.

Why does the question of a *normative* aspect of time occupy you?

Of course one can use a purely descriptive term like *time* in a normative context, e.g., *Use the remaining time!* But then it is the imperative, which is normative, not the term *time*.

Comment: so Aristotle would say it doesn't matter when anything happens ??

Comment: i simply do not believe it! i won't downvote your answer tho because surely it's the fault of the question

Comment: Of course it matters whether I appear today or tomorrow, when a meeting is scheduled for tomorrow. But it is not the term *time* which is is normative but the imperative "Come to the meeting tomorrow at noon!".

Comment: not the "term" no, but a concept of "time" also defines what we can say about times like e.g. noon

Comment: Of course everybody uses the term *time* in descriptive propositions as well as in normative requests (= imperatives). But does the same not hold for nearly any concept?

Comment: you seem to understand the question now, what's the issue here ?

Comment: I wanted to emphasize the difference between a term, a proposition and a request. In my opinion, only the latter is normative. But probably a textbook of philosophy of language provides some deeper information.

Comment: the difference you outline makes sense, but i don't see its relevance if you understand the question, and i'm not sure how to make it any clearer - partly because i can't imagine many philosophers who say that "times" cannot be used in normative "imperatives"

Comment: @mathematician "white" is descriptive. But doesn't it matter to me whether my teeth are white? Sure it does. Your criteria for normativity is incorrect: "white" is not evaluative *per se*, and the fact that it can be embedded in normative statements doesn't change its descriptive nature.

Comment: @quen_tin what about "whiteness" ? if you want white teeth, do you consider "whiteness" an evaluative term? whatever your answer is, has no-one ever claimed that some facts cannot be "embedded in normative statements"? do you understand the original question ?

Comment: @mathematician a better criteria is that a terms consists in attributing a valuation (independently of what it applies to). "Good" is positive whether it applies to a person, an event, or whatever.

Comment: @mathematician I don't see how time could be normative in this sense. Attributing a specific time doesn't amount to attribute a valuation to something. There can be good and bad things happening at the same time, (in different places).

Comment: @mathematician same for whiteness: it is not evaluative per se, whiteness can be good or bad depending on what it applies to and other norms. Whiteness is not in itself a norm.

Comment: @quen_tin i'd have thought that some things aren't good (and aren't bad either). also, i'd have thought that some theories of time allow us to talk about the timing of specific events without thereby extending it to everything at that time

Comment: @quen_tin no not "in itself" but nowhere do i mention time "in itself" in the question :) another tiresome long discussion :(

Comment: @mathematician sure, but "normative", "thick", ... are second order predicates. They're general characteristics of predicates independent of specific applications.

Comment: @mathematician a concept is (or is not) normative "in itself". That's the proper understanding of normativity. If you want to distinguish all specific applications of time you cannot say "time has a normative aspect" but only "this occurence of time-predicate is normative in this context" which is very different.